# Sequelize - eager loading associations with optional scopes

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to load in 2 models that are associated to each-other. The problem is when using a scope similar to the documentation, it is a **required inclusion**

My scenario is with `Study` models having multiple `Product` models associated.

There are several `Study` models that do not yet have any `Product` associations (they were not initially created).

I have a scope defined as below:

```
const Study = sequelize.define(
  'study',
   ...
    scopes: {
      withProducts: {
        include: [
          {
            model: Product
          }
        ]
      },
```

There are 20 `Study` entries, but the following only returns 14 because 6 of the `Study` entries do not have any `Product` relationships.

```
const allStudies = await Study.scope('withProducts').findAll()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you have to explicitly set `required: false`

```
const Study = sequelize.define(
  'study',
   ...
    scopes: {
      withProducts: {
        include: [
          {
            required: false, // HERE
            model: Product
          }
        ]
      },
```

Comment: Much appreciated. I found that in the docs about 15 minutes ago. The docs read as `true` being the default, but alas!